# How to write lua-daemon for tarantool

Tags: lua, daemon, tarantool

How to write a lua-program for tarantool that will perform some tasks regularly (e.g. once per 10 minutes) in background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first way
Use [fibers](http://tarantool.org/doc/reference/fiber.html?highlight=fiber.create#lua-function.fiber.create). Fibers - is a set of instructions which are executed with cooperative multitasking. Fibers managed by the fiber package are associated with a user-supplied function called the fiber function. A fiber has three possible states: running, suspended or dead.

Example

```
fiber.create(function()
 while true do
   -- Let say you have space with tree index.
   -- Where each row index is timestamp + interval.
   -- So, here you can get lower/upper bound by current timestamp e.g.
   -- space:select{fiber.now()} -- get expired tasks
   fiber.sleep(1) -- interval
 end
end)
```

The second way
Use [expirationd](http://tarantool.org/doc/reference/expirationd.html?highlight=expirationd) - https://github.com/tarantool/expirationd